# Java Shadowing with Lambdas producing awkward behavior

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using DSL and Lambdas with the Spring Integration library and running into a weird issue.

I attempted to build an IntegrationFlow that would split file data at the newline character. When I had the lambda expression inline to the builder it worked fine:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(this.inboundStreamingMessageSource())
        .transform(new StreamTransformer("UTF-8"))
        .split(s->s.applySequence(true).get().getT2().setDelimiters("\n"))
```

In the above example the split method is receiving a Consumer of SplitterEndpointSpec. At that point I factored out the lambda into its own Field for readability:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(this.inboundStreamingMessageSource())
        .transform(new StreamTransformer("UTF-8"))
        .split(NewlineSplitter)
        ...

final Consumer<SplitterEndpointSpec<DefaultMessageSplitter>> NewlineSplitter = 
    s -> s.applySequence(true).get().getT2().setDelimiters("\n");
```

However, I get a stacktrace exception running this. Currently its:

> org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages

At another time, I got a Classcast exception stating that the type String.class could not be converted to SplitterEndpointSpec. If you look at the API documentation for the **IntegrationFlowDefinition** that I'm calling `split` from, you can see that the method is heavily shadowed: there are about 12 variations of differing parameter lengths. Is the compiler misinterpreting which version of split I'm calling?

I simply cannot see what would cause this behavior and am unsure if this is a Java 8 error or a problem with the Spring-integration implementation. I am using spring-integration-dsl 1.2.3.RELEASE and am probably stuck with that version at the moment due to the dependencies defined in another library built for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to exercise that `get().getT2().setDelimiters("\n")` - there is already a `delimiters()` option on the `SplitterEndpointSpec`:

```
s.applySequence(true).delimiters("\n")
```

Secondly it looks more like an issue of the compiler you use. Have just tested your use-case with the:

```
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

Works well without any complains and runtime errors.

On the other hand I use the latest Spring Integration. How about you? What version is in use?

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the delimiters option. I am not using the latest spring integration as aws-integration was not playing well with it. I'm using spring-integration-dsl 1.2.3 and updated my question to mention that since it is important.

Comment: Well, Spring Integration AWS is due to `2.0 GA` next week: https://spring.io/blog/2018/08/01/spring-integration-for-aws-2-0-0-rc1-and-spring-cloud-stream-kinesis-binder-1-0-0-rc1. Time to think about upgrade to the latest version!

Comment: In addition, I've been going through the source code here and in split and filter there seems to be a lot of bizarre logic based around class type, if the input is a lambda expression etc, that I think is causing this.

Comment: Good to know about the new version, things move a bit slow at the corporate environment I'm working in with regards to upgrades, however, and I prefer to get it working with this setup first.

Comment: Might be... Unfortunately we don't support that project if there is a workaround. If you really can reproduce that with the latest version, we will consider to fix if that is possible.

Comment: OK: I do think some of the reflection checking is the culprit and will "hack" around it. As a side note, your blog posts have been helpful in learning about this, especially as the javadoc is a bit scant for this project. So, thank you for that!

Comment: Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter and we will fix those Javadocs as well!